# Step builder with subclasses

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

A builder pattern with subclasses is a solved problem, so is a step builder when you have required parameters:

1. [Builder with subclasses](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2010/10/24/using-builder-pattern-subclasses#preferred)
2. [Step builder](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/building-smart-builders.html)

Anyone knows how to combine both?

I.e. we have subclasses and each subclass has different steps.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you might be going down the whole path here: you see, those two patterns already add a certain amount of complexity to your code and for sure things do not become **easier** when combining them.

And as you are not giving a specific example, I am suggesting to rather *step back*; and have a close look at your object model.

Meaning: *maybe* you should rather re-think and simplify your object model. Maybe the answer is not to combine subclassing, builder pattern and step builders; but to come up with a "simpler" class design that doesn't require all this "overhead" in order to be "useful" to you.

The thing that makes me "nervous" here is basically: classes should follow the single responsibility principle. And I am wondering if a class that needs a triple-concept-featuring builder to be useful ... could actually be doing "just one thing". Or if you are about to build some spaghetti thing that is already hard-to-deal-with right now; and now you hope to "recover" from that by adding this complicated builder approach.

Comment: In other words, the question exhibits the XY problem.

Comment: Maybe. No feedback since 4 hours; so who knows.

Comment: @jaco0646 I had two classes with final fields, therefore the step builder. What I did to solve the problem is some refactoring. Still my question is valid, because what do you do when you have subclasses with final fields, a normal builder pattern is not going to solve that.

Comment: Mine was just an idea; I am sure when you can put up a reasonable [mcve]; we might check if there is a nice solution for that problem.